# iOS iTunes FileSharing doesn't work

Tags: iphone, xcode8, ios10.3

I'm trying to save mp3 ringtone files using iTunes FileSharing but it doesn't work. All mp3 files are stored under supporting files.

```
NSString *fileName = @"demo.mp3";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *m4rPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *err = nil;
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:[m4rPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] error:&err];
        NSLog(@"%@",[err localizedDescription]);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!! I've solved it. I was doing silly mistake in copying file.

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath: m4rPath error:&err];
```